# Disable or Hide Save/Print Preview Dialog popups

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winforms-interop

I'm working with an ActiveX control placed on a winform.  I'd when the user tries to save or print, it will always show a dialog box first;  I'd like to either immediately close the dialog box or keep it from displaying in the first place.

The control in question does not raise any events that would let me know what button they pushed, so I can't really cancel it out by looking for an "on_print" notification.

Comment: What's the ActiveX control? Can you check with the provider of the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just sending escape via SendKey() whenever WM_ENTERIDLE was processed and that did the job.  Dirty hack, but it worked.